# Initializing multidimensional dynamical array in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having problems declaring a multidimensional dynamical array in c style. I want to declare dynamically an array like `permutazioni[variable][2][10]`, the code i'm using is as following (`carte` is a class i defined):

```
#include "carte.h"

//other code that works

int valide;    
carte *** permutazioni=new carte**[valide];
for (int i=0; i<valide; i++){
   permutazioni[i]=new carte*[2];
   for (int j=0; j<2; j++) permutazioni[i][j]=new carte[10];
}
```

the problem is, whenever i take `valide=2` or less than 2, the code just stops inside the last `for (int i=0; i<valide; i++)` iteration, but if i take `valide=3` it runs clear without any problem. There's no problem as well if i declare the array `permutazioni[variable][10][2]` with the same code and any value of `valide`. I really have no clue on what the problem could be and why it works differently when using the two different 3d array i mentioned before

Comment: better use std::vector<>

Comment: You'll have a whole lot of problems trying to properly manage that memory. Use containers e.g. `std::vector`

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code you posted. What do you mean when you say it "stops inside the last iteration?"

Comment: *I'm having problems declaring a multidimensional dynamical array in c style*  -- Your code does not declare any multidimensional arrays.  A multidimensional array would be simply `carte permutazione[10][10][10];`.

Comment: @JamesRoot i mean that it doesn't get out of the first `for` (the one that with `valide`) to continue on the rest of the code, it just stucks there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show a 3D array declared as `permutazioni[variable][10][2]` but when you tried to dynamical allocate that you switched the last two dimensions.

You can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define NVAL    3
#define DIM_2  10 // use some more meaningfull name
#define DIM_3   2

// assuming something like
struct Card {
    int suit;
    int val;
};

int main() {
    // You are comparing a 3D array declared like this:
    Card permutations[NVAL][DIM_2][DIM_3];

    // with a dynamical allocated one
    int valid = NVAL;    
    Card ***perm = new Card**[valid];
    // congrats, you are a 3 star programmer and you are about to become a 4...
    for ( int i = 0; i < valid; i++ ){
        perm[i] = new Card*[DIM_2];
        // you inverted this ^^^ dimension with the inner one

        for (int j = 0; j < DIM_2; j++)
            // same value   ^^^^^
            perm[i][j] = new Card[DIM_3];
            // inner dimension    ^^^^^
    }

    // don't forget to initialize the data and to delete them

    return 0;
}
```

A live example [here](https://ideone.com/rDV9IZ).

Apart from that it is always a good idea to check the boundaries of the inddecs used to access to the elements of the array.

Comment: Sorry for the variables names, should keep that in mind; I'm not really a  programmer, though. Anyway, i haven't inverted the two dimensions. What i meant to say it's that whenever i try to allocate an array like `permutation[NVAL][2][10]`  that code gives me problems whit some values of `NVAL`. These problem doesn't shows when i invert the two last dimension and allocate an array like `permutation[NVAL][10][2]` instead of the one before. Please tell me if i haven't understood what you meant to write. I think i'll give vector a try this time

Comment: @luigi how do access the elemnts of the arrays? Sure that you don't incur in an out bound access to the elements of the array? meaning that if you declare an array like `int a[10][2][3]` then a[10] is not valid, a[9][1][2] is valid, a[2][2][2] it's more tricky, is out of bounds, but arrays are contiguous in memory so maybe your program don't complain.

Comment: I really thanks you for taking the time to answer and help me. I thought that could be a problem, as i wrote in the comments above the code stucks inside the first `for` I use, the one that iterates on the variable `i=0; i<valide`, so I thought that could be due to an out of bound problem, but I can't really spot it.

Comment: I just noticed that if i comment out a part of the code following the one i posted, a part where i actually use the array `permutation[NVAL][2][10]` to store variables, the code runs without getting stuck, so i assume it's an out of bound problem that shows up when i try to use it.

Comment: @luigi check carefully the values of all the variables involved in the allocation and as indeces when using the array, the problem is there

Comment: Finally resolved it, it was about the variable `valide` and how I used it to initialize when I needed to associate values to the array. I'm new to this site, is there a way I can thank you for the help? like some kind of score or something similar

Comment: @luigi you just did it accepting the answer ;) that's how you can thank. You can also upvote any answer you find helpfull. You are welcome BTW

Answer (score 0):

How about using this syntax? Haven't tested fully with 3 dimensional arrays, but I usually use this style for 2 dimensional arrays.

```
int variable = 30;
int (*three_dimension_array)[2][10] = new int[variable][2][10];

for(int c = 0; c < variable; c++) {
    for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            three_dimension_array[c][x][i] = i * x * c;
        }
    }
}
delete [] three_dimension_array;
```

Obviously this could be c++ 11/14 improved. Could be worth a shot.

Comment: It could be improved by using C++98 too